# X.509: No key store or PEM while connecting SAP HANA by Python HDBCLI

Tags: python, hana

I am writing a simple script to connect SAP HANA, But I got a weird error. Hope anyone give me some advice.
Here is my code:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
import json

with open('./configure.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
    address = config["host"]
    port = config["port"]
    username = config["user"]
    password = config["password"]

print(address, port, username, password)

connection = dbapi.connect(
    address=address,
    port=port,
    username=username,
    password=password,
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

The error message is :

> ```
> F:\Scripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:\Scripts\main.py 
> 172.17.0.44 30115 XXXXXX XXXXXX_2017
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "F:\Scripts\main.py", line 13, in <module>
>   connection = dbapi.connect(
> hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (-10709, 'Connection failed (RTE:[-1] X.509: No key store
> or PEM provided (0.0.0.0:10976 -> 172.17.0.44:30115))')
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

I guess maybe I need to install some key on my PC, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be grateful.

[image]

I read the official document, but got no resolution. Hoping any suggestions.

My PC os is Windows 11 and my python version is 3.10.11

Comment: Hi, it looks like what you need is an `SSL Certificate` to connect. You can go ahead and see the following https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/18/setting-up-app-router-for-hana-xsa-with-python for guidance as here he authenticates with a certificate file.

Comment: @Muneeb Ahmad Khurram Hi, the reason is I don't have hana client on my computer.  Thanks a lot to your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a progress to above question. I installed sap hana client on my computer then the error gone.
(sap hana client has hdbcli@2.11.14, I downgrade my python version to 3.8.6 to fit it.)
But I got another error occoured.

```
F:\Scripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:\Scripts\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Scripts\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    connection = dbapi.connect(
hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (-10709, 'Connection failed (RTE:[0]  172.17.0.44:30115)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I could connect to this hana instance through my computer's hana client. So I am sure the network is ok. Hope any other possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

dbapi.connect() method need a variable "user", not "username". But when I wrote "user", pycharm alert me Unexpected argument, the connect is ok; when I wrote "username", pycharm looks everything is ok, the connect throw errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxSH5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BASmH.png)

Answer (score 0):

We have had this same issue inside a docker container based on a microsoft-dotnet image. We didn't experience the issue inside the official python:3 image. It turned out that we needed to additionally install the libkrb5-dev library. After that, everything worked for us.